# Equation of a line parallel to $5x-3y=7$ That goes through the point (3,-1)

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, functions

This is a study question in preparation for my midterm. It's multiple choice. The answers are:

A) $y=(5/3)x-(7/3)$

B) $y=(3/5)x-(14/5)$

C) $y=(5/3)x-6$

D) $y=-(3/5)x+(4/5)$

Here is my process:

$5x-3y=7$

Move the 3x over and change the sign.

$5x=3y+7$

Move the 7 over and switch it to negative.

$3y=5x-7$

Divide entire formula by 3.

$y=(5x/3)-(7/3)$

Which is answer A), so I know that answer A is not correct, since this is not a parallel line, it is the same line.

Now I use the point slope equation:

$y-y_1=(5(x-x_1))/3$

$y+1=(5(x-3))/3$

$y=(5x-15-1)/3$

$y=(5x-16)/3$

So I know only (C) can be the correfct answer, since it has the same slope as the original equation, but my y intercept is off in my equation. I would appreciate some help as to how to arrive at the $-6$ in answer C.

Also, I don't know how to create fractions on this forum, any correction of my equations for clarification would be appreciated.

Comment: -15-3=-18 not -14.  That's where you made an arithmetic error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just made an arithmetic error trying to do two things at once. $$y=\frac{5(x-3)}3-1=\frac{5x-15}{3}-1=\frac53x-5-1=\frac53x-6$$

Comment: Oh I see, this makes more sense, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You multiplied $5$ times $3$ and got $14$.  It should be $15$.  Then you need to bring the $1$ from $y+1$ over.

Comment: I simply skipped a step, I'll add it to my question if it clarifies things.

Comment: Just seeing now that it should have been $-16$ not $-14$

Comment: @user2435 You have to subtract the $1$ after you distribute the $\frac{5}{3}$.  So, multiply $-3$ by $5$ to get $-15$.  Then divide by three to get $-5$.  Then subtract $1$ to get $-1$.

Answer (score 0):

The line in question has the same slope as yours since they are parallel, so the slope $m=5/3$. Using the point-slope equation of the line we obtain $y+1=(5/3)(x-3)$, or $y=(5/3)x-6$.